# Vim, Long Lines and Scrolling

Tags: vim, editing

I use Vim to edit English text files with >10.000 words and long paragraphs. The files are formatted as plain text and each paragraph is a long line. I use the `wrap` option, and I bind `j` and `k` to `gj` and `gk` respectively so I can move by display lines.

If my cursor is on the top of the screen (but not the beginning of the document) and I move the cursor up (using `gk`), the screen scrolls up to display the whole long line (a 300-word paragraph). The problem is that because of the length of the line this makes the screen scroll by half of the screen. This is disorienting because I don't know beforehand how much the screen will move. Scrolling with `^Y` has the same problem.

Is there a way to make Vim scroll by just one display line when using `gk` and its ilk? This is more natural for editing non-source-code and the default behavior in most text editors as well as in word processors, but not in Vim. I think this would mean that Vim would have to stop insisting on showing the entire line I'm editing.

Comment: There were a few questions already on this subject; I don't recall now what were the conclusions though, but have you tried just splitting the paragraphs. 10000 words is not really a usual definition of a sentence (or a paragraph for that matter).

Comment: A paragraphs is 300 words long, sentences are obviously shorter than that; for Vim, a paragraph is just a line (a line not being identical to a sentence). The entire document contains 10,000 words. It is clearly not an option to write shorter paragraphs because of the scrolling behavior of the editor used! If you recall a previous discussion of my problem, I would be grateful for a pointer -- all I could find were questions about `wrap`, `gj` and `gk`.

Comment: This has been a long lasting limitation of Vim. Search google for "vim scrolling wrapped line": it seems to have been a common request for the last 10 or 15 years. There are no known elegant solutions, maybe Vim is not the right tool for the job?

Comment: @loevborg - For vim a paragraph is not a line. Paragraphs can have EOF chars. in them, and standard way to navigate them are via { }, so I see no reason why they should need to be that long.

Comment: There are also options regarding Vim's behaviour concerning paragraphs, for more see "help paragraph" - it will tell it better than I ever can.

Comment: @romainl - There has not been any elegant solutions, partly because people don't really know what they would consider an elegant solution. For five nines of people sentences (and rightly so) do not go over several dozens of words, and paragraphs are considered a reasonable number of sentences. Putting a whole works of Tolstoj in one line is certanly not the way to go, and should never (EVER) be made a pretext for regulating the default options of an editor.

Comment: @ldigas, I agree. Actually I don't think it's a limitation at all: the habit of other text editors/processors to allow lines to be cut visually in the middle of the line height and paragraphs to be displayed partially as always bugged me.

Comment: Idigas, your comments are not helpful and beside the point. Thanks romainl for the suggestion! I don't understand why you think that Vim is not the right tool for writing longish texts.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally fixed this problem by switching to hard wrapped prose documents. I don't believe there is any other solution. Here's one of the articles that first exposed me to the idea: http://alols.github.io/2012/11/07/writing-prose-with-vim/

I must confess that, in the beginning, the idea to convert all my documents to this old-fashioned way of writing text files looked annoying as hell to me, and it'll probably do to you too. But I soon realized by trying other modern editors that none of them was as powerful and stable as Vim. All it took me before this felt completely natural was some `formatoptions` tuning. In my case, this works best:

```
setlocal formatoptions=wat
```

Also, here's one handy function I discovered to go back to soft wrap at anytime which you might find useful: [Unwrap text in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039544/unwrap-text-in-vim/23034108#23034108)

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you define a macro to scroll your page.  If you have a screen height of 50, you could go with something like:

```
map zp 48gj
```