# How to unwrap text in Vim?

Tags: vim

I usually have the `tw=80` option set when I edit files, especially LaTeX sources. However, say, I want to compose an email in Vim with the `tw=80` option, and then copy and paste it to a web browser. Before I copy and paste, I want to unwrap the text so that there isn't a line break every 80 characters or so. I have tried `tw=0` and then `gq`, but that just wraps the text to the default width of 80 characters. My question is: How do I unwrap text, so that each paragraph of my email appears as a single line? Is there an easy command for that?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Go to the beginning of you paragraph and enter:

<kbd>v</kbd>
<kbd>i</kbd>
<kbd>p</kbd>
<kbd>J</kbd>

(The `J` is a capital letter in case that's not clear)

For whole document combine it with norm:

```
:%norm vipJ
```

This command will only unwrap paragraphs. I guess this is the behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose this is the easiest method available then? Nothing that does this for the whole document in one go I presume?

Comment: @Ray I've edited my answer and add the command to execute for the whole document.

Comment: It is better to use the `:normal` command with `!`-specifier in this case to avoid clashes with custom mappings.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need to go to the beginning of the paragraph. The point of "ip" in that command, is that it will grab the entire paragraph that you are in, whether or not you're at the beginning.

Comment: @Derek you are right. I know the movement tags like at, iB, etc..(combining movements with i and a). But i wanted to give clear answer without any distraction.

Comment: Wow! I didn't want to `J` each line. I should've known I could `J` multiple with Vim. What's more, you can go to the next paragraph afterwards and hit `.`.

Answer (score 11):

Since joining paragraph lines using Normal mode commands is already
covered by another answer, let us consider solving the same issue by
means of line-oriented Ex commands.

Suppose that the cursor is located at the first line of a paragraph.
Then, to unwrap it, one can simply join the following lines up until
the last line of that paragraph. A convenient way of doing that is to
run the `:join` command designed exactly for the purpose. To define
the line range for the command to operate on, besides the obvious
starting line which is the current one, it is necessary to specify
the ending line. It can be found using the pattern matching the very
end of a paragraph, that is, two newline characters in a row or,
equivalently, a newline character followed by an empty line. Thus,
translating the said definition to Ex-command syntax, we obtain:

```
:,-/\n$/j
```

For all paragraphs to be unwrapped, run this command on the first line
of every paragraph. A useful tool to jump through them, repeating
a given sequence of actions, is the `:global` command (or `:g` for
short). As `:global` scans lines from top to bottom, the first line
of the next paragraph is just the first non-empty line among those
remaining unprocessed. This observation gives us the command

```
:g/./,-/\n$/j
```

which is more efficient than its straightforward Normal-mode
counterparts.

Comment: There's a little bug in this command: if you have a one line paragraph it gets glued to the beggining next paragraph.

Comment: @Omar:  Great catch, thank you!  The answer has been updated to address this case.

Comment: I was doing it like in @fatih's answer, but for some reason that joins very short paragraphs together, so I came here looking for alternatives and this works great, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The problem with `:%norm vipJ` is that if you have consecutive lines shorter than 80 characters it will also join them, even if they're separated by a blank line. For instance the following example:

```
# Title 1

## Title 2
```

Will become:

```
# Title 1 ## Title 2
```

With ib's answer, the problem is with lists:

```
- item1
- item2
```

Becomes:

```
- item1 - item2
```

Thanks to [this forum post](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Does-automated-quot-line-unwrap-quot-exist-td1157525.html) I discovered another method of achieving this which I wrapped in a function that works much better for me since it doesn't do any of that:

```
function! SoftWrap()
    let s:old_fo = &formatoptions
    let s:old_tw = &textwidth
    set fo=
    set tw=999999 " works for paragraphs up to 12k lines
    normal gggqG
    let &fo = s:old_fo
    let &tw = s:old_tw
endfunction
```

Edit: Updated the method because I realized it wasn't working on a Linux setup. Remove the lines containing `fo` if this newer version doesn't work with MacVim (I have no way to test).