# Vim: Convert hard wrap to soft wrap

Tags: linux, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unwrap text in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039544/unwrap-text-in-vim)

How to convert hard wrap into soft wrap in a text file, using vim or (if simpler) some other standard GNU/Linux tool? And this while preserving paragraphs as such. It would be easy to remove all line breaks, but not serviceable.

By hard wrap I mean a document where each line ends at most at (for example) column 80.

I noticed that the program aquamacs has a function to do this, but I don't know what its output looks like, and it is Mac OS X only.

Comment: What is a soft wrap and how do you insert one in a text file?

Comment: @n.m. - I believe "soft wrap" would be what you get when using Vim's wrap option, while hard wrap would be the same as the effect of gq and tw (inserting line breaks).

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
:%norm vipJ
```

It will unwrap all the paragraphs in you text. However, if you want to do it manually, simply do `ipJ` inside visual mode on each paragraph you want to unwrap.

---

I also found [another way](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Does-automated-quot-line-unwrap-quot-exist-td1157525.html) to achieve this

```
:g/^\s*\n.*\S$/+norm vipJ
```

which means:

```
:g  "Execute command when pattern matches
```

Pattern:

```
^\s*\n  "A line with only spaces or tabs (or none)
\n.*\S$ "A line with anything but ending with a non-space character
```

Command:

```
+norm vipJ "Join the lines in the paragraph
```

Please note that you'll need an empty line before the first paragraph too.

Comment: I will add a detail I forgot. Take for example any text file from the vim user guide. Can I unwrap paragraphs and leave unaffected the code/input listings ? On a portable device, it shows up very r
agged with those linebreaks.